# scale_fill_discrete and scale_fill_manual - legend options confusion

Tags: r, colors, plot, ggplot2, scale

I have a problem with applying two different changes on my `ggplot2` object. I have a barplot with 3 groups on it. I want to:

1. set color for each group
2. reorder the order of legend labels

I have found the following solutions to the above problems:

1. `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"))`
2. `+ scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))`

The problem is the second application (`+ scale_fill_discrete(...)`) is overriding the first one:

```
Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale.
```

(separately both of them work fine). How to deal with it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You do not need to make it double, this should work:

```r
scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"), name = "My name", 
                  guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```